# How to calculate restricted mean survival time for covariates in R?

Tags: r, survival

I am trying to calculate the restricted mean survival time grouped by the covariates but I get an error. Could you please have a look at the code example code below and let me know what the problem is?

```
library(survival)
library(flexsurv)

data <- survival::lung
formula <- Surv(data$time, data$status) ~data$sex
fsmodel_exponential<-flexsurvreg(formula,dist = "exp")

#Produces the expected results
rate_exponential<-fsmodel_exponential$res[1]
rmst_exp <- rmst_exp(t = 30, rate = rate_exponential, start = 0)
rmst_exp

#Gives error for the covariate
rate_exponential_sex<- fsmodel_exponential$res[2]
rmst_exp2 <- rmst_exp(t = 30, rate = rate_exponential_sex, start = 0)
rmst_exp2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `fsmodel_exponential$res[2]` is negative, which causes an error. In the exponential model covariates on these parameters represent an accelerated failure time (AFT) model. You do get those when you invert the factor levels of `sex`, which results in positive maximum likelihood estimates.

```r
library(survival)
library(flexsurv)
data <- lung
data$sex <- relevel(factor(data$sex, labels = c("M", "F")), "F")
formula <- with(data, Surv(time, status) ~ sex)
fsmodel_exponential <- flexsurvreg(formula, dist = "exp")
rmst_exp(t = 30, rate = fsmodel_exponential$res[1], start = 0)
#> [1] 29.23162
rmst_exp(t = 30, rate = fsmodel_exponential$res[2], start = 0)
#> [1] 1.998406

plot(fsmodel_exponential, col = c("blue", "red"), 
    lwd.obs = 2, xlab = "months", ylab = "Recurrence-free survival")
legend("topright", levels(data$sex), col=c("red", "blue"), lty=1)
```

[image]

**Edit:**
To get the RMST, simply run:

```
summary(fsmodel_exponential, type = "rmst", t= 30 )
#> sex=M 
#>   time     est      lcl      ucl
#> 1   30 28.7467 28.49528 28.94901
#> 
#> sex=F 
#>   time      est      lcl      ucl
#> 1   30 29.23162 28.98571 29.40346
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! However, I'd like to know if there is a way to calculate the RMST for both curves at the same time? E.g. 29.23 for the females in your example, but how much is it for men?

Comment: @gibsonmate: see edit in my answer - `summary(fsmodel_exponential, type = "rmst", t= 30)` would give it for `t=30`, for example. See `?summary.flexsurvreg` for more details.